# How to refrest the content of a page using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, redirect, refresh, reload

I wanna refresh the content in a page, for example like when you like a photo in facebook, you can notice the text change from like to not like and the number of likes increase or decrease.
I'm doing using a redirection to the controller, the problem is that the page go to the beginning and I don't want that. anyone know what I need to do to stay in the same part of the page and that the fields changes?

Comment: Use JavaScript for asynchronous operations that change the page without a full refresh. This is how pages load data via AJAX.

Comment: Please try to do even 30 seconds worth of research before posting your question here.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer Mike Lyons. I read that about AJAX but I was wondering if there was another way to do it, I guess I have to learn AJAX xD.